# Stopping shared link - sharepoint

Tags: vba, sharepoint, power-automate

Is there any possibilities to end (or make limited time) for shared document in sharepoint?
I mean: everyday I have to upload document with ddl to edit. I do it everyday and I would love to make it from editable to read only after specified hour?
I don't want nobody to edit it after the end of the day...

Is there any chance that enables such a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: That sounds more like a PowerShell script to modify the file permissions instead of a VBA solution.

Comment: Ok! I didn't thought about this. But it seems to be very hard to create for me for this moment. I know VBA more than PowerShell. but anyway, thank you for an advice - I will search more in internet